# Latex Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{sidewaystable}

Tags: errors

I get the following error when compiling my LaTeX source:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{sidewaystable}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.98
```

The table causing the problem, which is defined in chapter1.tex, and included in the main document by `\include{chapter1}`, is:

```
\afterpage{
  \clearpage
  \begin{sidewaystable}
    \begin{center}
      \scalebox{0.75}{
        \begin{tabular}{p{4cm}|c|p{4cm}|p{5cm}l|ll|l|}
          \hline
          \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Time Complexity}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Space Complexity} \\
          \hline
          Author
            & Year
            & Method
            & $m < n$
            & $m = n$
            & $m < n$
            & $m = n$ \\
          \hline
          \hline
          ...
          \hline
        \end{tabular}
      }
      \caption{Time and space complexity of algorithms used to calculate Hermite Normal Form matrices measured in terms of the matrix dimension, $n$, by letting $M = O(n^c)$ for some constant $c$, and $m = O(n)$.  Such conversions will be denoted by $O^{\thicksim}$(*).}
    \end{center}
  \end{sidewaystable}
  \clearpage
}
```

The main source file uses the `report` document class.  It also uses the following packages:

```
\usepackage{uowthesis}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
```

Apart from some `\newtheorem` and `\newcommand` statements, there is nothing spectacular about the main source file that should cause it to behave this way unless, of course, the `\afterpage` statement (above) interferes with the `\beforepreface` and `\afterpreface` statements, also included in the main source.

Note that I have decided not to paste the main source file as sample code in this question due to space limitations.  Also, due to breach of confidentiality, intellectual property, etc.  However, I can elaborate on certain portions of the main source if requested and, if necessary.

## Modification: bill 3-JAN-2012 - Added sample main file.

Here's an abridged version of the main file that can be used to cause/show the problem.  Hope it helps.

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{uowthesis}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\begin{document}

%
\title{Optimal Key Lengths and Digital Signatures}
\author{Vasilios Evangelos Tourloupis}
\dedicate{My Family}
\degree{Master of Computer Science}
\dept{School of Computer Science and Software Engineering}

\beforepreface
%\include{abstract}  % Abstract
%\include{acknowledgement}   % Acknowledgements}
%\include{papers}    % Publications

\afterpreface

\include{chapter1} % Introduction
\include{Chapter2} % Background
\include{Chapter3} % Efficient Self-Certified Signatures with Batch Verification
\include{chapter4} % Self-Certified Ring Signatures
\include{Chapter5} % Conclusion


%\bibliographystyle{alpha}
%\bibliography{thesis}   %\include{NoCites}   % Important references (probably not cited before)


\end{document}
```

Comment: Try compiling a minimal example. If you suspect that `\afterpage` is interfering, why not try commenting it out and seeing if you get the same error?

Comment: @Seamus - Can't include small example, as it would require pasting the entire style file defining the package `uowthesis`.  Commenting out `\afterpage` alone did not solve the problem, however, commenting out the whole table did.  Therefore, it must be a problem with the table (which I highly doubt as this is a straight copy and paste from an article class paper that had no problems compiling).

Comment: Does compiling it with `table` work instead of sidewaystable? If it does, this might be because of a redefinition/undefinition of the sidewaystable environment (probably in your custom thesis class).

Comment: @recluze - while commenting out `sidewaystable` eliminated the error, it caused the following error: `! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.`  I therefore tried repositioning `\caption` so that I won't get that error, however, no success.  I suspect that you are right about the redefinition of `sidewaystable`.

Comment: That error is expected. That's why I said replace it with `table` so that you get an equivalent float.

Comment: Bill, you say that a MWE would require `uowthesis` (which means that the error does not occur without it), so it seems it's the main reason for the problem you have. So we need the `uowthesis` package for an analysis of the problem.

Comment: http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/uowthesis

Comment: Actually, I don't think this is the same "UoW" since a MWE using `UoWthesis` as document class doesn't lead to an error.

Comment: No. Actually, from @Bill 's profile, it is the right UoW. So I don't know why he's using it as a package rather than a class…

Comment: Here is _a_ version of `uowthesis.sty` http://lecture.cs.buu.ac.th/~s47232/latex/UoW/uowthesis.sty

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt - Valid point about the problem being with the style file.  Seamus - Yes, it appears to be the same version of the style file that I am using and, although a unix `diff` spits out the entire file as being different compared to the one I copied from a fellow student, a visual inspection does not indicate so.  Either way, I get the same problem no matter which uowthesis.sty file I use.

Comment: P.S. To all and sundry - Note that I have modified the question to include an abridged version of the main source file which is adequate enough to cause/show the problem occurring.

Comment: The added code doesn't tell anything, as we don't have access to the part that *really* triggers the error.

Comment: @egreg - Yes you do - this is in the link that Seamus has provided above.  Also, the problematic table that I have provided in the question is enough to cause the problem.

Comment: The package `uowthesis.sty` is old and creates many problems. In particular the definition of `\@xfloat` is buggy. Commenting it makes the problem disappear. However I discourage using such a buggy package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`uowthesis` is an old LaTeX style written for LaTeX 2.09. Especially the redefinition of `\@xfloat` is not compatible to LaTeX2e. As a workaround one can save the definition of `\@xfloat` before including the `uowthesis` style, and do a proper redefinition afterwards:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

% Save \@xfloat
\makeatletter
\let\@xfloat@ORI\@xfloat
\makeatother

\usepackage{uowthesis}

% Redefine \@xfloat in a way which works with LaTeX2e
\makeatletter
\def\@xfloat#1[#2]{%
  \@xfloat@ORI{#1}[{#2}]%
  \def\baselinestretch{1}\@normalsize} % This line taken from uowthesis
\makeatother

\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

  \begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{p{4cm}|c|p{4cm}|p{5cm}l|ll|l|}
          \hline
          \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Time Complexity}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Space Complexity} \\
          \hline
%          ...
          \hline
        \end{tabular}
      \caption{Time and space complexity of algorithms...}
  \end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Note that this isn't up-to-date coding either. A better approach would be using the `setspace` package for that purpose. The `setspace` enables single spacing for floating environments and footnotes automatically, so no need to patch `\@xfloat` and `\@footnotetext` as done in `uowthesis`.

Comment: Thanks for that!  It solved the problem!  Seems like UoW will have to review their style file....

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: @Bill: LaTeX2e was released in 1994! So after nearly two decades they definitely should "review" their templates.

Answer (score 4):

You probably opened something that you didn't close.  (It could be in the source doc, or it could be in the expansion of some macro.)

Comment out things until you have something that works.  Then add back.  At that point you know the offending piece.

Comment: @JimHeffron - That's probably something I will have to painstakingly do.  I was hoping that by posting to the group, somebody would have seen the problem before, and therefore know how to resolve it quickly.  Unfortunately, that does not appear to be the case.  Thanks for the advice anyway.

Comment: Using dichotomy, you should be able to see quickly what line is the wrongdoer.